# How to show text with central align

Tags: android

how to show textview like this image?

[image: mockup]

my textview will look like this image

[image: screenshot]

below is my code, it's not showing text centrally:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/imagelogo2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/options1" />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="If your school is not in the list.Please check" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="back later or contact your district&apos;s Nutrition Services" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="department for more information" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace

```
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
```

with

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

for all the TextView. Try the layout below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/imagelogo2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/options1" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="If your school is not in the list.Please check" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="back later or contact your district&apos;s Nutrition Services" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="department for more information" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is all your 3 TextViews are different widths, so "center" is different for each of them.

Change them all to:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center"

    >

        <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/text" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:gravity="center"
          android:textStyle="italic"
          android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:text="If your school is not in the list.Please check"
            />

        <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/text" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:gravity="center"        
          android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:textStyle="italic"
          android:text="back later or contact your district's Nutrition Services"
            />

        <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/text" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:gravity="center"        
          android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:textStyle="italic"
          android:text="department for more information"
            />
```

Comment: android:typeface="Times New Roman" is not allowed in xml. You can use only one among normal,sans,serif and monospace for typeface in xml.

Comment: how many type face and style android allow?? where i get list??

Comment: In xml,if you type android:typeface and press = and wait eclipse itself will list those stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 3 textviews you should use one textview.

and the text that you want to show, had to convert it to HTML.

```
String code = "<p><b>First, </b><br/>" +
                "Please press the <img src ='addbutton.png'> button beside the to insert a new event.</p>" +
                "<p><b>Second,</b><br/>" +
                "Please insert the details of the event.</p>"
                "<p>The icon of the is show the level of the event.<br/>" +
                "eg: <img src = 'tu1.png' > is easier to do.</p></td>";

        message = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.message);       
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(code, this, null);
        message.setText(spanned);
        message.setTextSize(16);
```

and make textview gravity to center.

For Times New Roman Fonts you need to do this:

- create one folder "fonts" in assets folder
- copy times new roman.ttf file in "fonts" folder. (times fonts file
  should be in small caps)

then add this class to your activity class:

```
public class Typefaces{

        private final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

            public Typeface get(Context c, String name){
                synchronized(cache){
                    if(!cache.containsKey(name)){
                        Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                                c.getAssets(), 
                                String.format("fonts/%s.ttf", name)
                            );
                        cache.put(name, t);
                    }
                    return cache.get(name);
                }
            }

        }
```

then try this code:

```
Typefaces tf = new Typefaces();
tvMessage.setTypeface(tf.get(context, "timesnewroman"));
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: <font face=\"arial\" color=\"red\">"+
  "This paragraph is in Arial, size 5, and in red text color." + "</font>" try if it helps.

Comment: i don't think you have times new roman option as typeface in android. you need to use custom fonts.